# using old jQuery with script made on new jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have made a plugin with new version of jquery and when client is using my plugin they get a error uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(...).
According to this problem is raised when jquery is of older version.
My client not want to upgrade the his jquery version as he thinks it will break his website because he is using many other plugins which is depended on older version of jquery.

I tried convincing him to use one more jquery with newer version just before my script but he didn't agreed.

can anyone give me any possible solution so that they can use my script because I dont want to change my script of $ to jQuery.

Comment: `TypeError: $ is not a function(...)` mostly appears when there is NO jquery at all on the page or it has not loaded when $ is used. But investigate [jQuery.noConflict](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Comment: what version of jquery does he got and version you got?

Comment: this is more like a namespace problem then a version problem

Comment: Did your client import jquery core lib before using your lib??

Comment: make sure you include the jquery on your html

Comment: @madalinivascu what do u mean  by namespace problem ?

Comment: i mean using jQuery instead of $ to reference jquery,most likely the site is a wordpress cms site

Comment: its a cms Drupal site. you can check it here http://www.tnp.sg/ @madalinivascu

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like not a version conflict, but it's caused by name of jQuery class. Try wrapping your code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    /// ... your code
});
```